cc -o out out.s on macOS with M1 chip
I have been learning the chapter of 04_Assemblyhttps://github.com/DoctorWkt/acwj/tree/master/04_Assembly. According to the README.md, after I typed cc -o comp1 -g cg.c expr.c gen.c interp.c main.c scan.c tree.c and./comp1 input01, I got an output 15 and a file out.s:
    .text
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
printint:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
    nop
    leave
    ret

    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    $2, %r8
    movq    $3, %r9
    movq    $5, %r10
    imulq   %r9, %r10
    addq    %r8, %r10
    movq    $8, %r8
    movq    $3, %r9
    movq    %r8,%rax
    cqo
    idivq   %r9
    movq    %rax,%r8
    subq    %r8, %r10
    movq    %r10, %rdi
    call    printint
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret

After that, I got an error. If i typed cc -o out out.s, I got :
out.s:5:8: error: unknown token in expression pushq %rbp ^ out.s:5:8: error: invalid operand pushq %rbp ^ out.s:6:7: error: unknown token in expression movq %rsp, %rbp ^ out.s:6:7: error: invalid operand movq %rsp, %rbp ^ out.s:7:12: error: unknown token in expression subq $16, %rsp ^ out.s:7:12: error: invalid operand subq $16, %rsp ^ out.s:8:7: error: unknown token in expression movl %edi, -4(%rbp) ^ out.s:8:7: error: invalid operand movl %edi, -4(%rbp) ^ out.s:9:9: error: unexpected token in argument list movl -4(%rbp), %eax ^ out.s:10:7: error: unknown token in expression movl %eax, %esi ^ out.s:10:7: error: invalid operand movl %eax, %esi ^ out.s:11:11: error: unexpected token in argument list leaq .LC0(%rip), %rdi ^ out.s:12:11: error: unknown token in expression movl $0, %eax ^ out.s:12:11: error: invalid operand movl $0, %eax ^ out.s:13:2: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic, did you mean: casl? call printf@PLT ^ out.s:15:2: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic leave ^ out.s:19:2: error: unknown directive .type main, @function ^ out.s:21:8: error: unknown token in expression pushq %rbp ^ out.s:21:8: error: invalid operand pushq %rbp ^ out.s:22:7: error: unknown token in expression movq %rsp, %rbp ^ out.s:22:7: error: invalid operand movq %rsp, %rbp ^ out.s:23:11: error: unknown token in expression movq $2, %r8 ^ out.s:23:11: error: invalid operand movq $2, %r8 ^ out.s:24:11: error: unknown token in expression movq $3, %r9 ^ out.s:24:11: error: invalid operand movq $3, %r9 ^ out.s:25:11: error: unknown token in expression movq $5, %r10 ^ out.s:25:11: error: invalid operand movq $5, %r10 ^ out.s:26:8: error: unknown token in expression imulq %r9, %r10 ^ out.s:26:8: error: invalid operand imulq %r9, %r10 ^ out.s:27:7: error: unknown token in expression addq %r8, %r10 ^ out.s:27:7: error: invalid operand addq %r8, %r10 ^ out.s:28:11: error: unknown token in expression movq $8, %r8 ^ out.s:28:11: error: invalid operand movq $8, %r8 ^ out.s:29:11: error: unknown token in expression movq $3, %r9 ^ out.s:29:11: error: invalid operand movq $3, %r9 ^ out.s:30:7: error: unknown token in expression movq %r8,%rax ^ out.s:30:7: error: invalid operand movq %r8,%rax ^ out.s:31:2: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic cqo ^ out.s:32:8: error: unknown token in expression idivq %r9 ^ out.s:32:8: error: invalid operand idivq %r9 ^ out.s:33:7: error: unknown token in expression movq %rax,%r8 ^ out.s:33:7: error: invalid operand movq %rax,%r8 ^ out.s:34:7: error: unknown token in expression subq %r8, %r10 ^ out.s:34:7: error: invalid operand subq %r8, %r10 ^ out.s:35:7: error: unknown token in expression movq %r10, %rdi ^ out.s:35:7: error: invalid operand movq %r10, %rdi ^ out.s:36:2: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic, did you mean: casl? call printint ^ out.s:37:11: error: unknown token in expression movl $0, %eax ^ out.s:37:11: error: invalid operand movl $0, %eax ^ out.s:38:7: error: unknown token in expression popq %rbp ^ out.s:38:7: error: invalid operand popq %rbp ^ .
I realized that my platform is arm. So, I downloaded x86_64-elf-gcc, and I got:
/opt/homebrew/opt/x86_64-elf-binutils/bin/x86_64-elf-ld: cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory /opt/homebrew/opt/x86_64-elf-binutils/bin/x86_64-elf-ld: cannot find -lc: No such file or directory collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
Is there any way to help me solve this?
My enviroment:
macOS 14.5 with m1
I guess qemu can be used to run my x86_64 code?

You need to install the C library too but note that if you are on ARM then the code will not run anyway. Better install linux into an x86-64 VM.

Your code is for amd64 Linux whereas your system is arm64 macOS.  This won't work.  Install Linux in an amd64 (x86-64) VM and follow the tutorial therein.

@Jester Yeah, I guess qemu can be used to run my x86_64 code? So, How to install C library on my macos?

That won't make this code work.  MacOS uses a leading _ on symbol names, and IIRC might not use the same @PLT for shared-library symbols.  And clang wants some different assembler directives for macOS than for Linux.  Also, the system-call numbers and calling convention aren't identical, if later examples are going to use syscall directly.  So running this as a macOS process under Rosetta might not work as well as Linux, even if you are prepared to translate the symbol names in the examples.

@PeterCordes I don't care about performance, I just hope he can run the code normally. So, Do you have any recommended methods? Using qemu to run the code generated by x86_64-elf-gcc
or using Rosetta (how to do this method specifically if using Rosetta)?

The difficulties you might run into with this or later examples would be correctness, not performance.  Like having to edit the asm to port it from Linux to macOS.  So you'd have to know both and what the differences are, which you won't if you're just following a tutorial that's trying to teach super basics.  Find a tutorial for your OS (x86-64 macOS via Rosetta 2, or ARM64 macOS native), or set up an environment that matches your tutorial (x86-64 GNU/Linux, e.g. with docker or a VM.)

If you can write C code that runs on macOS, you can compile it with -arch x86_64 and -S to emit Intel assembly, so then you have working examples to look at.
